# How correct use swiperjs breakpoints with React jsx file?

Tags: reactjs, slider, breakpoints, swiper.js

Iam using [swiperjs](https://swiperjs.com/) dependencies to create an amazing slider. But, I got an error while using one of API controller, which is breakpoints. I need this controller for customization the display. But, when I applied this, I got an error like this :v
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtW3v.png)

Here is my code :

```
<Swiper
    centeredSlides={true}
    grabCursor={true}
    pagination={{
        dynamicBullets: true,
    }}
    breakpoints: {
    // when window width is <= 1024px
        1024: {
            slidesPerView: 4,
            spaceBetweenSlides: 150
        },
        // when window width is <= 768px
        768: {
            slidesPerView: 3,
            spaceBetweenSlides: 200
        }
    }
    modules={[Pagination]}
    className="mySwiper"
>
    {events.map((event, idx) => {
      return (
        <SwiperSlide>
          <CardEvent
            image={event.img}
            info={event.info}
            title={event.name}
            icon={event.ico}
            color="bg-white"
          />
        </SwiperSlide>
      );
    })}
</Swiper>
```

Anybody can help me how to use breakpoints?

Answer (score 1):

`breakPoints` syntax is wrong. that's why you see that error. Try the below syntax. Refernce sandbox [url](https://codesandbox.io/s/bhl8e?file=/src/App.jsx:487-783)

```
breakpoints = {{
        1024: {
            slidesPerView: 4,
            spaceBetweenSlides: 150
        },
        768: {
            slidesPerView: 3,
            spaceBetweenSlides: 200
        }
    }}
```

Comment: `spaceBetweenSlides` is now `spaceBetween`